# What is the meaning of confusing sentence?

Tags: meaning

[Source](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1045658/synopsis)

> Tiffany offers to deliver a letter to Nikki, if in return he will be
>   her partner in an upcoming dance competition.

What is the meaning of confusing sentence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the confusing bit is **if in return**.

When you do something for somebody, you might expect them to do something for you as well. You are expecting them to do something **in return**.

Often this is agreed in advance, for example:

> Me: Can you pick up my dry cleaning on the way home?
>   You: Sure, I can do that- if you bring some pizza for dinner **in return**.

What the confusing sentence means is that Tiffany offers to deliver Pat's letter to Nikki if Pat agrees to be Tiffany's partner in the dance competition.